# Advanced Rest Client - Dont show response

Tags: windows, advanced-rest-client

I had a big problem with **ARC**. It usually do not show response. I must send that same request many times to get response (sometimes on first request show it, sometimes i must send it 30 times). Application always return some think *(i log it)*, but `ARC` do not want to show it. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi,
Is it Chrome or desktop version of the app? I am the author of the app and I never seen behaviour like this. Is there any error message when the response isn't rendered?

Comment: I got this issue on chrome and desktop. On chrome in most cases i got only a part of response. On windows i got all or got anything. I dont have any error message or anythink.